# Delegate's method being called from one class, but not another class with identical structure

Tags: objective-c, methods, uinavigationcontroller, delegates, uistoryboardsegue

I have three classes. `AlertDetailsVC`, `UtilizationDetailsVC` and `SelectIOVC`.

`UtilizationDetailsVC` is essentially a copy of `AlertDetailsVC` with some small modifications.

When a user opens up the `Scene` for my `AlertDetailsVC` he can press a button in a `Table` called `Applies To`. When he presses this `Applies To` button, the program then `Segues` to a new `Scene` which uses `SelectIOVC`; it then sets the `Delegate` of that scene equal to the `Delegate` defined in the `AlertDetailsVC`.

Then when the user hits `Done` on the `Navigation Bar` on the `SelectIOIOVC` `Scene`; the `SelectIOVC` class then returns some data and information that the user selected back to the `AlertDetailsVC`.

This flow is similarly copied in the `UtilizationDetailsVC`.

I added several `NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);` lines in my methods that should be being called.

Now; when I hit `Done` in my `AlertDetailsVC` the methods are correctly called and the program `Segues` back from `SelectIOVC` to my `AlertDetailsVC` and updates the information on that page the user entered.

however my problem is; when I do the exact same thing in my `UtilizationDetailsVC` page; and press its' `Done` button; the program does not `Segue` back.

I am not sure; my logs show that the first `SelectIOVCDidSave` is called in the case of `AlertDetailsVC`; but it is not ever called by `UtilizationDetailsVC`.

Relevant Code:

Utilization:

```
`UtilizationDetailsVC.h`:

@class UtilizationDetailVC;

@protocol UtilizationDetailsVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)utilizationDetailsVCDidCancel: (UtilizationDetailVC *)controller;
- (void)utilizationDetailsVCDidDelete: (UtilizationDetailVC *)controller;
- (void)utilizationDetailsVCDidSave: (UtilizationDetailVC *)controller;

@end

@interface UtilizationDetailVC : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, SelectTimeVCDelegate, SelectDaysVCDelegate, SelectIOVCDelegate, SelectIODetailsVCDelegate, SelectTimeLengthVCDelegate, MessageVCDelegate, UtilizationContactsVCDelegate, SelectDateVCDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NCUtilization *utilization;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <UtilizationDetailsVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellEnabled;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *startTimeField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *endTimeField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *allDayField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *daysField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *days;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *appliesToField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notifyWhenField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *changeExistsForField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contactsField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contactUUIDs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *startDateField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *startDate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *endDateField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSDate *endDate;


- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

UtilizationDetailsVC.m relevant methods:

```
- (void)selectIOVCDidCancel:(SelectIOVC *)controller
{
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)selectIOVCDidSave:(SelectIOVC *)controller
{
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    // Update input/output information with user selection on UI.
    self.appliesToField.text = controller.ioDescription;
    self.notifyWhenField.text = @"";
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

Alerts:

AlertDetailsVC.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
#import "NCAlert.h"
#import "SelectTimeVC.h"
#import "SelectDaysVC.h"
#import "SelectIOVC.h"
#import "SelectIODetailsVC.h"
#import "SelectTimeLengthVC.h"
#import "MessageVC.h"
#import "AlertContactsVC.h"

@class AlertDetailsVC;

@protocol AlertDetailsVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)alertDetailsVCDidCancel: (AlertDetailsVC *)controller;
- (void)alertDetailsVCDidDelete: (AlertDetailsVC *)controller;
- (void)alertDetailsVCDidSave: (AlertDetailsVC *)controller;

@end

@interface AlertDetailsVC : UITableViewController <UITextFieldDelegate, UIActionSheetDelegate, SelectTimeVCDelegate, SelectDaysVCDelegate, SelectIOVCDelegate, SelectIODetailsVCDelegate, SelectTimeLengthVCDelegate, MessageVCDelegate, AlertContactsVCDelegate>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NCAlert *alert;
@property (weak, nonatomic) id <AlertDetailsVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSIndexPath *indexPath;

@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableViewCell *cellEnabled;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *titleField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITextField *descriptionField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *startTimeField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *endTimeField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *allDayField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *daysField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *days;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *appliesToField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *notifyWhenField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *changeExistsForField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *localAlertField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISwitch *localAlertAudioField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *contactsField;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSArray *contactUUIDs;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *messageField;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

AlertDetailsVC.m relevant methods:

```
    - (void)selectIOVCDidCancel:(SelectIOVC *)controller
{
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}

- (void)selectIOVCDidSave:(SelectIOVC *)controller
{
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
    // Update input/output information with user selection on UI.
    self.appliesToField.text = controller.ioDescription;
    self.notifyWhenField.text = @"";
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}
```

SelectIOVC:

SelectIOVC.h

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SelectIOVC;

@protocol SelectIOVCDelegate <NSObject>

- (void)selectIOVCDidCancel: (SelectIOVC *)controller;
- (void)selectIOVCDidSave: (SelectIOVC *)controller;

@end

@interface SelectIOVC : UITableViewController <UIPickerViewDelegate, UIPickerViewDataSource> {
    NSArray *selectIOType;
    NSArray *selectIO;
}

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIBarButtonItem *doneButton;

@property (weak, nonatomic) id <SelectIOVCDelegate> delegate;
@property (weak, nonatomic) NSString *identifier;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIPickerView *picker;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger type;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger io;
@property (assign, nonatomic) NSUInteger number;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *ioDescription;

- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender;
- (IBAction)done:(id)sender;

@end
```

SelectIOVC.m relevant methods:

```
- (IBAction)cancel:(id)sender
{

    [self.delegate selectIOVCDidCancel:self];
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);
}

- (IBAction)done:(id)sender
{
     NSLog(@"%s",__PRETTY_FUNCTION__);

    NSString *typeDescription = [selectIOType objectAtIndex:self.type];
    NSString *ioDescription = [selectIO objectAtIndex:self.io];
    self.ioDescription = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %@ %01d", typeDescription, ioDescription, self.number];
    [self.delegate selectIOVCDidSave:self];
}

- (void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setDoneButton:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
}
```

Comment: Very often when the delegate does not do anything, it's because I forgot the set the delegate. For example, you might have some line that looks like `UtilizationDetailVC udvc = [UtilizationDetailVC alloc] init];` and then you might forget this line `udvc.delegate = self;`.

Comment: I actually `Synthesize` the delegate of the `UtilizationDetailVC` in the respective .m file. Then I set all of the other delegates (The `SelectIOVC` for example) as you had stated.

Comment: @DinoTw the weird thing is; my `SelectIOVC`'s `Done` method is called. However, my `SelectIOVCDidSave` inside my `UtilizationDetailVC` is never called.

Comment: @DinoTw in which case; both are called correctly in respect to my `AlertDetailsVC`.

Comment: Solved it; refer to my post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this problem; I use a method called `- (BOOL)shouldPerformSegueWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier sender:(id)sender` in both my `UtilizationDetailsVC` as well as my `AlertDetailsVC`.

However; my mistake was I never set the `Segue Identifier` for the `Segue` between `UtilizationDetailsVC`'s `Scene` and the `SelectIOVC` `Scene`.

Setting the value to my according `Identifier` that I was checking for fixed my problem.